# Identification of geometry overlaps with PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I seem to have a problem getting basic functionality of postGIS to work:

- I have a table with polygons (stored in a text field) of municipalities
- I am drawing a circle around a coordinate (lat/long) with a certain radius

Now I want to check which municipalities are "touched" by or are within this circle (see attached image)

I have tried all kinds of things but do not suceed. Already the attempt of checking, whether a certain municipality is touched by the circle fails... I think it should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    points.common_name, 
    municipalities.id, 
    municipalities.name
FROM points, municipalities
WHERE 
ST_OVERLAPS(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(points.latitude,points.longitude),1000),
            (ST_GeomFromText(municipalities.geoPolygon))) 
            = TRUE
```

However, this is not giving any results.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction?

Regards,
krille

Comment: I think you have the coordinates the wrong way round in you makepoint (should be (lon,lat))... I think you still might have trouble, because the SRID is unknown and I'm guessing your buffer will calculate in degrees at the moment... You either need to set an SRID and project it to something more useful, or convert your geometries to geographies...

Comment: `st_intersects` should be enough, or, even better, don't create the buffer but instead select using `st_dwithin`. And then add a spatial index over the polygons.

Answer (score 0):

OK, great, [JGHs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7635569/jgh) solutions was spot-on! Code looks now like and works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

```
SELECT 
    points.common_name, 
    municipalities.id, 
    municipalities.name
FROM points, municipalities
WHERE 
ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(points.longitude,points.latitude)::geography,
            ST_GeomFromText(municipalities.geoPolygon)::geography, 10000) AND points.id = something
```